# How to integrate payment gateway in a normal WordPress Website?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, payment-gateway

Actually I am about to create a new website for internet service provider.People can get to know about all the tariff plans of internet as well as they can go for a customize plan.For a user friendly cooperation I want to use a payment gateway there where they can pay for internet usages.But I have no idea how to **integrate payment gateway** in that site.

Let me tell you I have already used payment gate in woo-commerce website.As **no woo-commerce** will be used in that website.So let me know will I need to install woo-commerce plugin in that website to integrate payment gateway or there is any alternative way to use payment gateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well woo-commerce is one of the easiest plugins for payment gateway's in my opinion. However there are various plugins for it [See here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/payment-gateway). Or do you want to make your own payment gateway? In that case check the page of the gateway you want (in example paypal) and check their site that could help you as well.

Comment: So will it be better to install woo commerce and then use payment gateway plugin?

p.s: I am not going to see anything in this website.

Comment: The link works for me, however I think that woocommerce would indeed be the easiest and a more simple option, it comes with a bunch of payment portals and you can get more via it too.

Comment: @ RDAxRoadkill ... Thank you so much. :)

Comment: @SumanKalyanMohanty not a problem, there are various tutorials online on how to set it up, if my anwser helped you consider to add it as the accepted answer so you can close this question ;)

Comment: @ RDAxRoadkill  DONE.are you on any social media like fb,twitter? Would be happy to be in contact with you.

Comment: Sended a contact thing via fb feel free to ask there if needed, always glad to help

Answer (score 0):

One of the best free plugin available is WooCommerce. 
Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

Comment: ..Can I use woo-commerce in a simple WordPress website where I am not going to sell products?

Comment: You can set it to catalog only mode. But if you need to integrate payment, then you should sell plans as a product. Alternatively, use something like Gravity Forms.